# Trying to write program that calculate the pell series to the nth element

Tags: c

I've just started learning C a few weeks ago and I'm currently writing a program to calculate the pell series to the nth element (given as an input). The first element needs to be 0 but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that (probably due to sleep deprivation).

The code works just fine and it calculates the pell series the only issue is that the first element isn't 0, and I cant just print 0 because the program should end without giving an output if the input is 0.

I know this question might look stupid but I would really appreciate some pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

  int n;
  int n1 = 1;
  int n2 = 0;
  int i;
  int pell = 0;

  printf("Enter how many pell numbers to print: \n");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i){

      pell = n1 + (2*n2);
      printf("%d" " ", pell);
      n1 = n2;
      n2 = pell;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears that your algorithm is wrong. Read https://www.javatpoint.com/pell-number-in-java

Comment: Thanks, @Mike I don't know how I didn't notice that my `printf`  was after the calculation and that was causing 0 to not get printed. I guess I can go to sleep now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Why the `"%d" " "`? Do you know that it can be written as `"%d "`?